# PHP Retain all decimals when using abs function

Tags: php

I'm using the abs function to get the positive value of a negative number as follows:

```
$totalTax = -4.50 ;
echo abs($totalTax);
```

which is working well except it is dropping the `0` and returns `4.5` instead of `4.50`.

Not sure why it's doing this or what the best method to retain all digits when using the abs function to convert a negative number to a positive? I need the 2 decimals regardless if the cents value is 0 for importing into an accounting system which only accepts 2 decimals and not 1.

Comment: It is not `abs` that is "dropping" anything here. Do a `var_dump($totalTax);`, and you will see that _that_ value already does not contain a trailing zero any more - for the simple reason, that _numbers_ do not ever have those. Your issue is one of _formatting_ numeric values to your desired look, when you output them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because how PHP outputs leading/trailing zeros - trims them. Because there is infinite number of zeros after last non-zero number

e.g. `echo 00000.1000000` will output `0.1`

You should format your number to keep that leading and trailing zeros.

```php
echo number_format($totalTax, 2, '.', '');
// -> 4.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `number_format()` function. There is no possibility to retain trailing `0` with using only the `abs()` function.

Here is code you try:

```
$totalTax = -4.50 ;
$total_sub = abs($totalTax);  
echo number_format($total_sub, 2);
```